# How can you make equations more aligned?

Tags: equations

Hello I want to do like this:

[image]

But I get like this
[image]

When I use this:

```
$3x + 4 \cdot (y+2) = 15 \\
 3y +4y + 8 = 15 \\
 7y + 8 = 15 {\color{red}| -8} \\ 
 7y = 7 \\ 
 y = 1$
```

Do you have any Tips?

Comment: This should be typeset as displayed math not text/inline (`$...$`). Please look up the `align` env from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: What should i look up?

Comment: @user279680 - The user guide of the `amsmath` package provides a really good overview of all multi-line display-math environments provided by the package, including the environment called `align`. For your use case, though, I would recommend that you go with an `array` environment, as I showed in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to suggest that you employ an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators
\begin{document}

\[ % enter an unnumbered displaymath group
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{ lClClCl }
3y & + & \multicolumn{3}{l}{4\cdot(y+2)} & = & 15 \\
3y & + & 4y & + & 8 & = & 15 \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{7y} & + & 8 & = & 15 \quad \textcolor{red}{\mid -8 } \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{7y} &&&       = & 7 \\
\multicolumn{5}{r}{y}  &         = & 1 
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: superhero


(Comments must be at least 15 characters in length)