# How to make Four Fields Board more aligned

Tags: tables, line-spacing

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c} 
&$\text{A}$&$\overline{\text{A}}$&\\ 
\hline
$\text{B}$&9&6&15\\ 
\hline 
$\overline{\text{B}}$&3&12&15\\ 
\hline
&12&18&30 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

But as you can see the B ist a little bit to near to the top.

Is there a way to make it more like this?

[image]

Comment: Please stop tagging all your questions as biblatex  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657763/how-to-make-an-equation-more-aligned#comment1638486_657763 This has _nothing_ to do with biblatex

Answer (score 3):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={cccc},hlines,vlines,rows={abovesep+={2pt}}}
                      & $\text{A}$ & $\overline{\text{A}}$ &    \\
$\text{B}$            & 9          & 6                     & 15 \\
$\overline{\text{B}}$ & 3          & 12                    & 15 \\
                      & 12         & 18                    & 30
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello I tried to enter it in Discord but i get following Error:
``! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.61 ...ccc},hlines,vlines,rows={abovesep+={2pt}}}
                                                  
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.``

Comment: @user279680 I am on TeX Live 2022. You can try it on Overleaf with 2022.

Comment: I want it to work on discord, the code that i posted worked on it

Comment: @user279680 Sorry, I don't know what is Discord? Can you give me a link describe it?

Answer (score 3):

(I added a second solution after the OP posted a follow-up request)

- First solution: Increase the value of `\arraystretch`. This affects the height of all rows.

  My main suggestion would be to execute `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}`. (The default value of this parameter is `1.0`.) Additionally, I'd like to suggest that you (a) employ an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment (saving you from having to type lots of `$` characters) and (b) replace `\overline` with `\bar. Finally, I'd usse` \mathrm`instead of`\text`.
- Second solution: insert typographic "struts" to increase the height and depth of selected rows.

  Note the use of `\TBstrut` in the third `array` environment in the following screenshot.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}

% Define typographic "struts", as suggested by Claudio Beccari 
% in a piece published in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993.
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand{\TBstrut}{\Tstrut\Bstrut} % top&bottom struts

\begin{document}
% default setup
\[
\begin{array}[t]{c|c|c|c} 
& \mathrm{A} & \bar{\mathrm{A}} & \\
\hline
\mathrm{B}      &9& 6&15 \\  
\hline
\bar{\mathrm{B}}&3&12&15 \\  
\hline
& 12 & 18 & 30
\end{array}
\qquad
% 1st solution: increase value of \arraystretch
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25} % <-- new
\begin{array}[t]{c|c|c|c} 
& \mathrm{A} & \bar{\mathrm{A}} & \\
\hline
\mathrm{B}      &9& 6&15  \\ 
\hline
\bar{\mathrm{B}}&3&12&15  \\ 
\hline
& 12 & 18 & 30
\end{array}
\qquad
% 2nd solution: insert typographic struts in rows 2 and 3
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1} % <-- reset to default
\begin{array}[t]{c|c|c|c} 
& \mathrm{A} & \bar{\mathrm{A}} & \\
\hline
\mathrm{B}      &9& 6&15 \TBstrut \\ % <-- note \TBstrut
\hline
\bar{\mathrm{B}}&3&12&15 \TBstrut \\ % <-- note \TBstrut
\hline
& 12 & 18 & 30
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you just do it for the second and third row also?

Comment: i like it more with arraystretch{1.25} but thank you already very much

Comment: @user279680 - Please see my updated answer, which provides an alternative answer that relies on inserting typographical struts in just rows 2 and 3 of the `array` environment. (I've also set the value of `\arraystretch` to `1.25` in the first solution.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `nicematrix` and `booktabs` (which provides the `\midrule` command).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, nicematrix, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c} 
&$\text{A}$&$\overline{\text{A}}$&\\ \midrule
$\text{B}$&9&6&15\\ \midrule 
$\overline{\text{B}}$&3&12&15\\ \midrule 
&12&18&30 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```